# How to create Model Class of Json Object - c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a Json object to which I want to bind to a model class. I have tried different ways of creating a class but the mapping deos not work and `rootObj` always return null properties, I think I am unable to generate a model according to the JSON string.

I am sharing two line code:

```cs
string serializedObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(nftList);
var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(serializedObj);
```

My json string `serializedObj` is:

```json
[
  {
    "json": "{\"Listing\": {\"Period\": 1209600, \"AssetID\": \"536d6f6f74685965746934333130\", \"Interest\": 1000, \"PolicyID\": \"eaa972045049185981aca9f4aaad38bc307776c593e4a849d3802a87\", \"Principal\": 300000000, \"BorrowerPKH\": \"ab77bec82618a2a5e8d891ad03361186a625861227605cb65f8ff312\"}, \"Deadline\": 1678360215, \"LenderPKH\": \"0b03d391a4746acf14794e4eaa531b67c25d69abed8512d0ecf35534\"}",
    "Principal": null
  },
  {
    "json": "{\"Listing\": {\"Period\": 1814400, \"AssetID\": \"424a533030393039\", \"Interest\": 600, \"PolicyID\": \"e282271ec9251ba23fb123b0f53618b35cf5a6cde4170c003a0ebf13\", \"Principal\": 70000000, \"BorrowerPKH\": \"155452c3bb66efa0e8493a018a2a16cdc7a5aaed1ae04020a2ef8dce\"}, \"Deadline\": 1679012316, \"LenderPKH\": \"e838596e09bee22eeb8615f6fc377582bab16ff9d961c6f74338c8ea\"}",
    "Principal": null
  }
]
```

I am trying Newton json

Comment: It would be very helpful to post the raw (and formatted) json and not a c# escaped version of it

Comment: This can be helpful too: https://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your JSON contains nested JSON. A reasonable model of your actual JSON is:

```cs
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("json")]
    public string Json { get; set; }

    // TODO: Possibly use a different type; we can't tell what
    // it's meant to be
    [JsonProperty("Principal")]
    public string Principal { get; set; }
}
```

You might then have a *different* class with `Listing` (which looks like it needs another class containing `Period`) etc. I'll call this `UsefulRoot` for now. (Ideally you'd give it a more meaningful name.)

To get from your original JSON to a `List<UsefulRoot>` you'd need to deserialize in two phases - once for the JSON objects represented at the top level, containing JSON, and then once for the `Json` property of each of them:

```cs
var roots = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(serializedObj);
var usefulRoots = roots
    .Select(root => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsefulRoot>(root.Json))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Could you please post complete model including Listing, Period etc? @jon

Comment: @ubaierj: No, that's work you should do yourself. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. I've explained to you what you need to do to proceed; it's up to you to do the rest of the work. I would strongly suggest that you stop looking at the JSON in the debugger though (where you'll see extra backslashes etc) and look at just the content of the `json` property *after* deserialization to a string, so that it's "just plain JSON" for the `UsefulRoot`.

Comment: thanks v much jon. may your kids live long and healthy. ameen

Comment: i got it now it is working like a charm. how can i vote you? jon skeet

Comment: @ubaierj: I *suspect* you can upvote the answer, and you should definitely be able to accept the answer (click on the tick next to the score). You don't *have* to do either of those, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You have another nested json inside of your json. So you will have to parse it twice, at first your json, after this nested json

```
List<Data> data = JArray.Parse(json)
                .Select(ja => new Data {
                Principal = (string)ja["Principal"],
                Listing = JObject.Parse((string)ja["json"]).ToObject<ListingItem>()
                }).ToList();
```

classes

```
public class Data
{
    public ListingItem Listing { get; set; }

    public string Principal { get; set; }
}

public class ListingItem
{
    public Listing Listing { get; set; }
    public int Deadline { get; set; }
    public string LenderPKH { get; set; }
}

public class Listing
{
    public int Period { get; set; }
    public string AssetID { get; set; }
    public int Interest { get; set; }
    public string PolicyID { get; set; }
    public int Principal { get; set; }
    public string BorrowerPKH { get; set; }
}
```